# Fetch(HTTP-Get) multiple class objects in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular-promise, http-get

Firstly, this is a little confusing to explain with my actual code, so I am trying to simplify the problem, with a smaller example.

Let's say my project receives data from 2 different tables in my server, *employeeDetails* and *employeeNames*.

**employeeNames:** This table has three columns, *employeeNumber*, *firstName*, and *lastName*. As the names say, this table has a list of all the employees, with their first and last name and a unique employee number.

**employeeDetails:** This table is where I httpGet and httpPost data from my website. For instance, let's say this table has the following fields:

- employee: Takes employee number as the input
- qualifications: Lets user input various qualifications as a string
- supervisor: Takes employee number of the supervisor, not the name
- manager: Takes employee number of the manager, not the name

While this is the case on the backend, the interface for *employeeDetails* on the frontend has a few more members. This is where it gets tricky.

On the frontend, this is how the angular interface looks:

```js
export interface employeeDetails
{
    employee: number;
    qualifications: string;
    supervisor: number;
    manager: number;
    employeeName: string;
    supervisorName: string;
    managerName: string;
}
```

So, I use httpGet to fetch data from the backend api, and once I receive both the tables, I have a function to populate the extra fields in the *employeeDetails* interface.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult getEmployeeNames()
{
        using (var empApp= new EmployeeTable())
        {
            var empNames = new List<employeeNames>();
            empNames = empApp.employeeNames.ToList();
            return Json(empNames);
        }
}

[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult employeeDetails()
{
        using (var empApp= new EmployeeTable())
        {
            var empDetails = new List<employeeDetails>();
            empDetails = empApp.employeeDetails.ToList();
            return Json(empDetails);
        }
}
```

**Service**

```js
  getEmployeeNames(): Observable<employeeNames[]> {
    return this.http.get<employeeNames[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/employeecontroller/getEmployeeNames')
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getItems', [])));
  }

  getEmployeeDetails(): Observable<employeeDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get<employeeDetails[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/employeecontroller/getEmployeeDetails')
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getItems', [])));
  }
```

**Component**

```js
getEmployeeInfo() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeNames()
      .subscribe(data => this.employeeNames = data);
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeDetails()
      .subscribe(data => this.employeeDetails = data);

    fillEmployeeDetails();
}

fillEmployeeDetails() {
    this.employeeDetails.forEach(elem => {
        let emp = this.employeeNames.find(employee => {
            return (employee.employeeNumber === elem.employeeNumber);
        });
        let sup = this.employeeNames.find(supervisor => {
            return (supervisor.employeeNumber === elem.supervisor);
        });
        let man = this.employeeNames.find(manager=> {
            return (manager.employeeNumber === elem.manager);
        });

        elem.employeeName = emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName;
        elem.supervisorName= sup.firstName + " " + sup.lastName;
        elem.managerName= man.firstName + " " + man.lastName;

    });
}
```

So, this function fails when I attempt to call it.
The reason is that the function is being called even before the entire employeeNames table is fetched. Without the table being fetched, .find() is returning null values for a lot of employee numbers, and so, my function doesn't return results as expected.

**MY QUESTION**

Should I use async/await and .toPromise() and avoid subscribing to the service in order to wait for the data to be fetched, or is there any better way?

Any help or thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the observable in order to initiate the HTTP request.
Also, you cannot call `this.fillEmployeeDetails();` like you do in the snippet, because the request is asynchronous and data will take some time to come back - the line of code where you call `this.fillEmployeeDetails`, however, will be executed immediately after firing the request.

When data comes back, the callback function inside subscribe is called with the request response as argument. You must call `this.fillEmployeeDetails();` inside subscribe, since you receive your data there.

But how can you know if both requests have returned already, i.e. can you start you `fill...` function?

Best solution is using a rxJs operator such as [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin), which - in this situation - behaves similarly to Promise.all(). That is to say, it only triggers its callback inside subscribe, when all observables (in your case, requests), have finished executing.

Essentially, your component code should look like so:

```
getEmployeeInfo() { // requests extracted in constants for readability
    const employeeNamesRequest = this.employeeService.getEmployeeNames();
    const employeeDetailsRequest = this.employeeService.getEmployeeDetails();

    forkJoin([employeeNamesRequest, employeeDetailsRequest])
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.employeeNames = data[0];
            this.employeeDetails = data[1];
            this.fillEmployeeDetails();
        })
}

fillEmployeeDetails() {
    this.employeeDetails.forEach(elem => {
        let emp = this.employeeNames.find(employee => {
        return (employee.employeeNumber === elem.employeeNumber);
    });
    let sup = this.employeeNames.find(supervisor => {
        return (supervisor.employeeNumber === elem.supervisor);
    });
    let man = this.employeeNames.find(manager=> {
        return (manager.employeeNumber === elem.manager);
    });

    elem.employeeName = emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName;
    elem.supervisorName= sup.firstName + " " + sup.lastName;
    elem.managerName= man.firstName + " " + man.lastName;

    });
}
```

Comment: I will definitely give this method a shot.
Additionally, I tried something else that I thought should work, but it seems to be having some issues. Here is an alternative approach that I thought could work. Please let me know if something is wrong in my approach here:


`async getEmployeeInfo() {
    this.employeeNames = await this.employeeService.getEmployeeNames().toPromise();
    this.employeeDetails = await this.employeeService.getEmployeeDetails().toPromise();

    this.fillEmployeeDetails();
}`

Comment: Yes, all in all, i think that your approach should work - even though it is suboptimal and goes against what angular promotes. Are the requests executing with status code 200? Do you get any errors while executing that code? Have you tried setting a debugger / console.log after requests have executed to see what the returned values are?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was out for the past few days. Anyway, I tried your method and it worked like a charm, the method using .toPromise() also worked, however, as you mentioned, I understand it is not angular way, so I used the forkJoin(). Thank you for the help.